# jQuery How to wrap sibling Div's with interruption

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given is the following HTML:

```html
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
<h1>Interruption</h1>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
```

What I need is the following:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
</div>
<h1>Interruption</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
</div>
```

Is there an easy way get this with jQuery? I found .wrapAll() but this will give me:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
  <div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
</div>
<h1>Interruption</h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **[`.nextUntil`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)** to indentify where `h1` occurs and use **[`.wrapAll`](https://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/)**.

```js
$('div[class^="ms-rteElement"]').each(function(){
 $(this).wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></div>').nextUntil('h1');
})
```

```css
.wrapper{
  background:orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
<h1>Interruption</h1>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-headline">Headline</div>
<div class="ms-rteElement-accordion-content">Content</div>
```

Comment: Well, i don't need to wrap each element, but all of them once

Comment: But you gave me the right hint. This should do what i need:
`code`
jQuery('*:not(.ms-rteElement-accordion-headline, .ms-rteElement-accordion-content) + .ms-rteElement-accordion-headline').each(function() {
 jQuery(this).nextUntil('*:not(.ms-rteElement-accordion-headline, .ms-rteElement-accordion-content)').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"></
  });
`code`

Comment: Cool.. I was trying it out.. Anyways you got the one you are looking for.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is useful

```
$( "h1" ).prevAll('.ms-rteElement-accordion-headline, .ms-rteElement-accordion-content').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
$( "h1" ).nextAll('.ms-rteElement-accordion-headline, .ms-rteElement-accordion-content').wrapAll('<div class="wrapper" />');
```

But you should enclose it inside a div

Answer (score -1):

Are you just looking for this? It's a pretty straightforward accordion [Jq accordian](https://jqueryui.com/accordion/)